# PHP Curl proxy wrong port

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have this code:

```
(...) //other options...
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "xxx.xxx.xx.xx");
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 17600);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.randomDomain.com");
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);

$data = curl_exec($this->curl);
var_dump(curl_error($this->curl)); 
//result is: "Failed connect to www.randomDomain.com:17600; Connection refused"
```

The curl error tells that I tried to connect with randomDomain on port 17600 - from proxy...

Why is this not port 80?

Answer (score 0):

Check access of your proxy and add this option to get response to $data

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```